# Is it possible to draw a single pixel to command prompt in python

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, game-engine

So i wanna create game engine with python. Running on command prompt.

I wanna know what method an draw a single pixel to command prompt.

Comment: Do you mean like a period? `.`

Comment: @JonSG Yes that it.

Comment: Can you add some code so we can see conceptually more about what you are attempting to do? Are you looking to `print()` a single or series of dots to the screen perhaps to show progress?  Are you looking to perhaps "prefill" the user response to an `input()` prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) may help you doing so, here's a quick example drawing a diagonal of points:

```py
import time
import curses

window = curses.initscr()
for x in range(30):
    window.addch(x, x, ".")
window.refresh()
time.sleep(1)
curses.endwin()
```

Keep in mind that the terminal has a character resolution: you won't be able to place pixels at any places.

But you can trick by using other chars than a dot, see for example the [bb](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/bb) demo:

```sh
apt install bb
DISPLAY= bb
```

(cleaning the DISPLAY variable to force it to run inside your terminal)

Comment: It's error, idk why. It's show module not found error in line 3 of "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\curses\__init__.py" --> from _curses import *